# Mysqli - return all rows with at least a match from string using INSTR()

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having issues with the query method below.
I am trying to do a search for possible matching strings in the database.

However, using `INSTR(fieldName, '".$q."')` returns a match only for exact words or for whole words.

For instance if `$q` contains "10th", it will return all rows that have "10th".
If `$q` contains "10th street" it will return all rows that have exact "two words".

But if `$q` contains two or more words from different rows as in "Sales, 10th Street", it will return nothing. That means, the server cannot find exact string in any of the rows.

So, I need to be able to return possible rows that have at least, a match in the `$q`.

Please go through my code and help me to modify it, to fit my purpose.

```
<?php
require_once('../data/conString_mysqli.php');//create connection


//$referrer = 'www.servicehub.ng/';
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "../servicehub.ng/find/index.php") {
    echo '<script>window.location="../home/?q=no query";</script>';
}

if (isset($_POST['services'])) {
    $q = trim($_POST['services']);
} else {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['q'])) {
        $q = trim($_REQUEST['q']);
    } else {
        if (isset($_REQUEST['s'])) {
            $s = trim($_REQUEST['q']);
        } else {
            header('Location:../home/');
        }
    }
}
?>

<div style="background: #f0ad4e;" id="menunavbar">
</div>

<section style="padding: 1.5em 0; background: #fdfdfd;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <form method="post" action="index.php">
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="form-control selectpicker" id="services" name="services" multiple
                                   data-max-options="1"
                                   placeholder="Enter a keyword to search by location, business type, business name, business items, sellers, market type etc"
                                   style="height:55px;">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-warning" type="submit"
                                                onclick="searchProvider(this.value)">
                                            <i class="fa fa-search" style="margin: 0;"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <div class="container">
        <table width="100%" border="1">
            <tr>
                <!--<td style="width:2%; border-radius:3px; height:45px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; background-color:#FF9933; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold; font-size:small;">S/N</td>-->
                <td style="width:12%; border-radius:3px; height:45px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; background-color:#FF9933; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold; font-size:small;">
                    Business Name
                </td>
                <td style="width:23%; border-radius:3px; height:45px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; background-color:#FF9933; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold; font-size:small;">
                    Business Address
                </td>
                <td style="width:23%; border-radius:3px; height:45px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; background-color:#FF9933; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold; font-size:small;">
                    Description
                </td>
                <td style="width:12%; border-radius:3px; height:45px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; background-color:#FF9933; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold; font-size:small;">
                    Contact Name
                </td>
                <td style="width:10%; border-radius:3px; height:45px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; background-color:#FF9933; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold; font-size:small;">
                    Category
                </td>
                <td style="width:10%; border-radius:3px; height:45px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; background-color:#FF9933; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold; font-size:small;">
                    Number/ Email
                </td>
            </tr>
            <div class="col-sm-9" id="dispSearch">


                <?php
                $search_query = mysqli_query($connect,
                    "SELECT * FROM service_providers WHERE INSTR(pname, '" . $q . "') OR INSTR(bizaddr, '" . $q
                    . "') OR INSTR(bizname, '" . $q . "') OR INSTR(bizdesc, '" . $q . "') OR INSTR(pmobile, '" . $q
                    . "') OR INSTR(pemail, '" . $q . "') OR INSTR(bizcat, '" . $q . "') OR INSTR(pmobile, '" . $q
                    . "')ORDER BY bizname"
                );

                $records = mysqli_num_rows($search_query);
                if (!$records >= 1) {
                    die('<script type="text/javascript">alert("Could not find any services related to your search. Please try another.");window.location="../home/?q='
                        . $q . '";</script>');
                } else {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_query)) {
                        $pcode   = $row['pcode'];
                        $bizname = $row['bizname'];
                        $bizaddr = $row['bizaddr'];
                        $bizdesc = $row['bizdesc'];
                        $pname   = $row['pname'];
                        $pmobile = $row['pmobile'];
                        $pemail  = $row['pemail'];
                        if ($row['bizcat'] == '') {
                            $category = "UNKNOWN CATEGORY";
                        } else {
                            $category = $row['bizcat'];
                        }
                        ?>

                        <?php
                        echo '
        <tr>
        <!--<td style="width:2%; height:45px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border:#FF6633; color:#FF6633; font-weight:500; font-size:smaller;">'
                            . $pcode . '</td>-->
        <td style="width:12%; height:45px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; border:#FF6633; color:#FF6633; font-weight:500; font-size:smaller;">'
                            . $bizname . '</td>
        <td style="width:23%; height:45px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; border:#FF6633; color:#FF6633; font-weight:500; font-size:smaller;">'
                            . $bizaddr . '</td>
        <td style="width:23%; height:45px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; border:#FF6633; color:#FF6633; font-weight:500; font-size:smaller;">'
                            . $bizdesc . '</td>
        <td style="width:12%; height:45px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; border:#FF6633; color:#FF6633; font-weight:500; font-size:smaller;">'
                            . $pname . '</td>
        <td style="width:10%; height:45px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; border:#FF6633; color:#FF6633; font-weight:500; font-size:smaller;">'
                            . $category . '</td>
        <td style="width:10%; height:45px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; border:#FF6633; color:#FF6633; font-weight:500; font-size:smaller;">'
                            . $pmobile . '; ' . $pemail . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        ';
                    }//end while
                }//end if($record)
                mysqli_close($connect);
                ?>
            </div>
        </table>

    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the 'LIKE' function for MySQL? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html This will allow you to search all rows for anything that has a pattern that matches the one that you specify IE: LIKE '$q';

Comment: LIKE is limited as well as INSTR(). If you have two words like ("john", "matthew") each in two fields, the LIKE does not perform search using each criterion. From Persons Table, Field1 is First Name, Field2 is Last Name. There are 3 rows. On Row 1, you have ("John" "Peter"). On Row 2, you have ("James" "Charles"). On Row 3, you have ("Matthew" "Conwell"). If your $q = "John Conwell", The query should search the entire table and return row 1 and row 3 respective. Because "John" is found in Row 1 while "Conwell" is found in Row 3. That is what I want.

Comment: You'll want to split the search expression into single words, then `INSTR(pname, '".$words[0]."') OR INSTR(pname, '".$words[1]."') OR INSTR(pname, '".$words[2]."')` and so on; append in a loop once for every search term. Note that this kind of query (lots of `OR`s) is a heavy operation for the RDBMS if you have many rows in `service_providers' .

Comment: This is a thought-to-be-good suggestion. I will try and implement it. If it works, it means, that the time for completing a search through 100s of 1000s of rows will be very long. Thanks for your suggestion. Let me give it a try.

Comment: But before I try splitting the string into an array(), I need you to understand the the table contains about 7 columns. Secondly, I do not know what is the length of the string that the user might type to do a search. So, I cannot prefix that. What is your best suggestion with regards to this please?

Comment: I was able to use an array() to split the string from user's input. $data = explode(" ", $q);
foreach ($data as &$q) {
$search_query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM service_providers WHERE INSTR(pname, '".$q."') OR INSTR(bizaddr, '".$q."') OR INSTR(bizname, '".$q."') OR INSTR(bizdesc, '".$q."') OR INSTR(pmobile, '".$q."') OR INSTR(pemail, '".$q."') OR INSTR(bizcat, '".$q."') OR INSTR(pmobile, '".$q."')ORDER BY bizname");
} It works but there is a challenge. Check the explanation below.

Comment: In the DB Table <Services_providers>, there are several rows of service providers. For Instance: <Provider Name>,<Services Category>,<Location>... On row 1, you have:<John>,<Cleaning>,<Washington> On row 2:<Peter>,<Transportation>,<Ohio> On row 3:<Charles>,<Catering>,<Washington>

Comment: The challenge: if a user searches with d keywords "cleaning services, Washington", d foreach($stringArray as $q) used in the query will return all rows with "cleaning", and "washington" instead of only d rows wit "cleaning" in d specified location "Washington". How can I solve this please? Thanks 4 ur help so far.

Comment: I reformatted some of your code so it is easier to read. Also try to put inline varibles inside backticks so they stand out of the rest of the text.